# Multiple row heights within one table

Tags: tables

In the first table `arraystretch` should be 1.4 and in the second 1.2. Solving this with two tables:

[image: how it is (two tables)]

doesn't allow me to align the vertical line ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwIrY.png)). However, I didn't find out how to have two different row heights in one table. How can I change the `arraystretch` value **within** one table?

Code:

```
\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Parameters:}} \\
    $I \cup J$ & set of customers\\
    $\beta_j^k$ & ... \\
    $f_j^k$ & ... \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{First stage variables}:} \\
    \def\arraystretch{1.2} % <-- doesn't do anything
    $r_i$ & open WH $i$\\
    $y_i$ & size of WH $i$
\end{tabular}
\def\arraystretch{1}
```

Comment: load `array` package and replace `c|` by `wc{2cm}|` or whatever width you want, then both tables will have the same width 1st column

Comment: Thanks, that fixes my specific problem! Is there a general way, though, to accomplish what I asked in the last line?

Comment: There is, but I wouldn't. You would have to globally reset arraystretch then globally recalulate `\strutbox` etc and then globally restore everything at the end,  why not ignore arraystretch and use `\\[20pt]` for the first set of lines and `\\[15pt]` for the second set

Answer (score 0):

With use of `tabularray` package you can write single table where all rows except rows with multi column cells (containing "subtitle") are separated with the same among vertical space:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1]{% for multi column cells with subtitle
    \ifnum\therownum=1
        \SetCell[c=#1]{l, mode=text, font=\bfseries}
    \else
       \SetCell[c=#1]{l, mode=text, font=\bfseries, cmd=\rule{0pt}{3ex}}
    \fi
                            }% end of NewTableCommand

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{vline{2},
             colspec = {Q[c, mode=math] l},
             }
\subtitle{2}   Parameters:          \\
I \cup J    &   set of customers    \\
\beta_j^k   &   ...                 \\
f_j^k       &   ...                 \\
...         &   ...                 \\
\subtitle{2}   First stage variables:      \\
r_i         &   open WH i           \\
y_i         &   size of WH i        \\
...         &   ...                 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]